# using twitter bootstrap with tabbed - ajax content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

so i understand bootstrap doesnt have default support for ajax called content for tabs, as jQuery UI does.

i have managed with the helps of other questions here, to come up with the following solution, that kind of works:

```
    <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1"> tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="ajax" href="test.html">tab 4 - ajax</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active"> tab 1 content </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane"> tab 2 content </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane"> tab 3 content </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('.ajax').click(function (e) {
              var thisTab = e.target // activated tab
              var pageTarget = $(thisTab).attr('href');
              //get number of li in list of tabs:
              var itemNumber = $(this).parent().index()+1;
              $("#tab"+itemNumber).load(pageTarget);

            });
        });
    </script>
```

this seems to work perfectly - it finds the destination href of the anchor, and it works out the order of the

.

i have 2 questions:

1) i want to work out programatically is tab #tab4 exists, and if so - then insert the content via ajax.
i am using:
          if ($("#tab"+itemNumber).length > 0)

but this seems to give the opposite result - ie, if it is there, it tells me its not.
whats up with that? - weird!

and 2) if i have i do have #tab4 (lets say i have put it in statically for now), then the content from test.html is loaded in successfully (yay) - but my issue is that now i cant get the tabs to switch to make #tab4 the active one.  I have tried applying the "active" class, and have also tried reapplying the tab() call, but that also doesnt work.

any ideas?

thanks in advance!

**EDIT: here is a jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/wnHEF/1/**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the 'active' class, and then applying it to the specific tab-pane seems to work.

```
$('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
$('#tab' + itemNumber).addClass('active');
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/wnHEF/3/)

---

Using `load()` in your JSFiddle example also works as expected in my example.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/wnHEF/4/)

Regarding dynamically creating the pane, your conditional test works for me, although it could be simplified:

```
if (!$('#tab' + itemNumber).length) { /* create new tab */ }
```

A simple test seemed to work fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log("#tab" + i + " found: " + !!$('#tab' + i).length);
}

// #tab0 found: false
// #tab1 found: true
// #tab2 found: true
// #tab3 found: true
// #tab4 found: true
// #tab5 found: false
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/wnHEF/6/)

Comment: Thanks for this!
but i tried changing the html() in the test, to load() and it doesnt seem to work anymore.
also, any comment about adding the div is dynamically if it doesnt exist?

Comment: @kneidels I've updated my answer. I suspect that your ajax call is violating the same origin policy. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Thanks merv, i appreciate the time on this. the console shows that the load() is working. then i found the issue. i had the "fade" class set on the tab, which is supposed to fade it in out, but for some reason it didnt. when i remove that - it showed up properly.  Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for Bootstrap 3 Tab and asynchronous tab load. Hope that it will help you.
Firstly, the markup for Bootstrap 3 Tab as normal. Note that the tab-content will have to store the ajax link to call if tab's content is empty. I used data-href to store it, you can change the attribute if you want.

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#basic" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Basic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#description" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#imdb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">IMDb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#subtitles" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Subtitles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#files" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Files</a></li>
    <li><a href="#peers" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Peers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tasks" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li></ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active fade in clearfix" id="basic">Basic content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="description">Description content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="imdb">IMDb</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="subtitles" data-href="subtitles.html"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="files" data-href="files.html"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="peers" data-href="peers.html"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tasks" data-href="tasks.html"></div></div>
```

And the jquery part to trigger the event tab change, check whether the content is empty or not. If it's empty, call the ajax function request the page which is stored in data-href to replace it.

```
<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    var id = e.target.hash;
    if($(id).html()==="") {
        ajax_call($(id).attr('data-href'),"GET",null,function(data){
            $(id).html(data);
        });
    }
});
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash && $('#tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
function ajax_call(url, type, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you man, i use this on bootstrap 3. I guess should work for version 2 too

Define you markut

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active blo_tabs"><a href="#blo_bor" data-toggle="tab"
          data-url="{% url "generar_bloque" %}"
          data-pars="listar=true&borrador&true"
          data-target="#blo_bor"
          >BORRADORES</a></li>
  <li><a class="blo_tabs" href="#blo_def" data-toggle="tab"
         data-url="{% url "generar_bloque" %}"
         data-pars="listar=true&definitivo&true"
         data-target="#blo_def"
          >DEFINITIVOS</a></li>
  <li><a class= "blo_tabs" href="#blo_proc" data-toggle="tab"
          data-url="{% url "generar_bloque" %}"
          data-pars="listar=true&enproceso&true"
          data-target="#blo_proc"
          >EN PROCESO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.blo_tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        tab = $(e.target); // activated tab
        warehouse_control.listar(
                tab.attr('data-url'),
                tab.attr('data-pars'),
                tab.attr('data-target')
        );
    });
</script>
```

This what warehouse_control.listar have.

```
listar: function(url, parametros, target){
        esperar.cubrir_especifico(target);
        $.get(url, parametros, function(response){
              $(target).html(response);
              esperar.descubrir();
         }, 'html' );
    }
```